# Window with tk to get text

Tags: python, window, tk-toolkit

I'm building a small educational app.

I already have all the code done, all I'm missing is a way is getting a window to open with TK displaying a textbox,  an image and a button.

All it should do, it return the text inserted in the textbox after clicking the button and closing the windows.

So, how do I do this?

I have been looking at code, but nothing I did worked, I almost fell ashamed being this so basic.

Thanks

Comment: The app is a command-line one?

Comment: Do you have any code examples of what you have tried so far with Tk so the community can see what might be wrong?

Comment: I'm happy to say I have no moved to PySide and learned how to use it. All this seems easier now.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to write GUIs is using Tkinter. There's an example that display a windows with a text and a button:

```
from Tkinter import*

class GUI:

    def __init__(self,v): 

        self.entry = Entry(v)
        self.entry.pack()

        self.button=Button(v, text="Press the button",command=self.pressButton)
        self.button.pack()

        self.t = StringVar()
        self.t.set("You wrote: ")
        self.label=Label(v, textvariable=self.t)
        self.label.pack()

        self.n = 0

    def pressButton(self):

        text = self.entry.get()
        self.t.set("You wrote: "+text)

w=Tk()
gui=GUI(w)
w.mainloop()
```

You may look at the Tkinter documentation, the label widget also supports to include pictures.

Regards

Comment: If you want to return the text, so, in the pressButton method you may exit the windows and then return the text.

Comment: Used your reply to structure what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This is a simple code that get the input from the `inputBox` to `myText`. It should get you started on the right direction. Depending on what else you need to check or do, you can add more functions to it. Notice you might have to play around with the order of the line `image = tk.PhotoImage(data=b64_data)`. Because if you put it right after `b64_data = ...`. It will gives you error. (I am running MAC 10.6 with Python 3.2). And the picture only works with GIF at the moment. See reference at the bottom if you want to learn more.

```
import tkinter as tk
import urllib.request
import base64

# Download the image using urllib
URL = "http://www.contentmanagement365.com/Content/Exhibition6/Files/369a0147-0853-4bb0-85ff-c1beda37c3db/apple_logo_50x50.gif"

u = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
raw_data = u.read()
u.close()

b64_data = base64.encodestring(raw_data)

# The string you want to returned is somewhere outside
myText = 'empty'

def getText():
    global myText
    # You can perform check on some condition if you want to
    # If it is okay, then store the value, and exist
    myText = inputBox.get()
    print('User Entered:', myText)
    root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()

# Just a simple title
simpleTitle = tk.Label(root)
simpleTitle['text'] = 'Please enter your input here'
simpleTitle.pack()

# The image (but in the label widget)
image = tk.PhotoImage(data=b64_data)
imageLabel = tk.Label(image=image)
imageLabel.pack()

# The entry box widget
inputBox = tk.Entry(root)
inputBox.pack()

# The button widget
button = tk.Button(root, text='Submit', command=getText)
button.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Here is the reference if you want to know more about the Tkinter Entry Widget: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Reference on how to get the image: [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086262/python-3-how-to-retrieve-an-image-from-the-web-and-display-in-a-gui-using-tkint)