# Unable to Load an Image from an URL at TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter, base64, python-imaging-library, urllib

My goal is to display an JPG image from an URL using tkinter python.

This is the [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086262/python-3-how-to-retrieve-an-image-from-the-web-and-display-in-a-gui-using-tkint) that I used as a reference. But when I try to run the code, I have received a bunch of error such as:

- KeyError: b'R0l.......
- AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'

Does anyone have the solution to this?

This is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from urllib.request import urlopen
import base64

root = tk.Tk()

URL = "http://www.universeofsymbolism.com/images/ram-spirit-animal.jpg"
u = urlopen(URL)
raw_data = u.read()
u.close()


b64_data = base64.encodestring(raw_data)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(b64_data)

label = tk.Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I can't get your example to work for me, but try specifying that you're passing in the `data` parameter with `ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=b64_data)`.

Comment: @Hobbes: I add the 'data' parameter and the first error (KeyError) disappears. But then a new error appears (OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x104deb620>) and the AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo' is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error is not specifying the `data` parameter within `ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=b64_data)`. However, I'm unsure why `PhotoImage` is unable to read base64 data.

A workaround would be to use `BytesIO` from the `io` module. You can pass in the raw data you read from the image into a `BytesIO`, open it in `Image` and then pass that into `PhotoImage`.

I found the code for opening the image from [here](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.open).

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from urllib2 import urlopen
from io import BytesIO

root = tk.Tk()

URL = "http://www.universeofsymbolism.com/images/ram-spirit-animal.jpg"
u = urlopen(URL)
raw_data = u.read()
u.close()

im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

label = tk.Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If anybody has a better answer as to why the encoding fails, it would be a more appropriate answer to this question.

Comment: Your code works only if I change 'StringIO' to 'BytesIO'. Thank you very much for this workaround solution.

Comment: BytesIO makes a lot more sense in this case. I've edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

Very similar but easier than Hobbes' answer, you can directly use the `data` parameter in the ImageTk.PhotoImage constructor:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from urllib.request import urlopen

root = tk.Tk()

URL = "http://www.universeofsymbolism.com/images/ram-spirit-animal.jpg"
u = urlopen(URL)
raw_data = u.read()
u.close()

photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=raw_data) # <-----

label = tk.Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```